# Insert image in pdf in php using mpdf

Tags: php, image, file, pdf, mpdf

Here,below is my code for converting an image into pdf using mpdf.
$html contains `upload/tulips.jpg`
But,when the function executes the pdf file created and an image icon shows there with the location `upload/tulips.pdf`.
Kindly tell me why this is happening because no bug is coming.

```
   private function ConvertImageToPdf($inputPath,$outputPath)
            { 
                $mpdf=new mPDF();
                $html='<img src='.$inputPath.'/>';
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                $mpdf->Output($outputPath.".pdf",'F');
                $mpdf->debug = true;

            }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$html='<img src="'.$inputPath.'"/>';
```

eg `""` around image-path, and you should be good (if the image exists)

In the mPDF-package `/examples` there is a `example04_images.php` you can try out.

PS : You should set `$mpdf->debug = true` *before* `$mpdf->Output()`

Answer (score 4):

its the comma problem

```
$html='<img src="'.$inputPath.'"/>';
```